# Creating a Reminder Discord Bot (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am writing my first Discord bot and I am fairly new to JavaScript, especially dealing with libraries such as Discord.JS. My project here is a Reminder Discord bot, which takes a user input by prefix, stores and checks data based on time, then outputs a user inputted message when the user time set is the same as current time (to alert).

My current issue is that I don't know how to send a message to a discord channel using the client outside of the two specificed scopes. Ideally, I'd like to send a message between

```
if (userTime === machineTime) {
        console.log("Reminder!");
        clearInterval();
    }
```

Thank you

````
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField, Permissions } = require(`discord.js`);
const { type } = require("os");
const prefix = '!';

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

var machineTime = null;
var userTime = null;

// Discord Client Ready Check

client.on("ready", () => {

    console.log("Bot is online!")

})

// Message Listener

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    //Split input into array & get current date

    var content = message.content.split(" ");
    console.log(content);

    // Output

    if (content[0] === prefix + 'set-reminder'){ 
        
        //Start timer
        setInterval(checkTime, 1000); 

        //Convert user time
        var inputTime = content[2].split(':');
        var inputDate = content[1].split('/');

        //Change store metrics and format date
        var convertMinutes = parseInt(inputTime[1]);
        var convertHours = parseInt(inputTime[0]);
        var convertMonth = parseInt(inputDate[0]);
        var convertDay = parseInt(inputDate[1]);

        var formatDate = convertMonth + "/" + convertDay + "/" + inputDate[2];

        //If PM add 12 hours to time input
        if (content[3].toLowerCase() === "pm") {
            convertHours += 12;
        }
        
        userTime = formatDate + " " + convertHours + " " + convertMinutes;

        //Send reminder confirmation
        message.channel.send("Members will be alerted at " + content[1] + ":white_check_mark:");

    } 

    // Input Array: 0 = prefix, 1 = date, 2 = time, 3 = am/pm, 4 = channel, 5 = message
})

//Current Time Check

const checkTime = () => {

    var machineOutput = new Date();
    var machineDate = machineOutput.toLocaleDateString();
    var machineMinutes = machineOutput.getMinutes();
    var machineHours = machineOutput.getHours();

    machineTime = machineDate + " " + machineHours + " " + machineMinutes;

    if (userTime === machineTime) {
        console.log("Reminder!");
        clearInterval();
    }

    console.log(machineTime);
}


client.login("MY_LOGIN_KEY");```
````

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have access to the client, you can send a message to any channel.

```js
if (userTime === machineTime) {
   console.log("Reminder!");
   clearInterval();

   const channel = await client.channels.fetch('channel id');
   channel.send('...');
}
```